Convergence of the sequence $b_n= \frac{a_n}{\max\{a_1, a_2, \cdots a_n\}}.$
Let $a_n$ be the sequence of positive reals. Let  $b_n= \frac{a_n}{\max\{a_1, a_2, \cdots a_n\}}.$ Which of the following statements is/are true?
$1.$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$ exists in $\mathbb R$ , then sequence $a_n$ is bounded.
$2.$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n =1 $ , then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exists in $\mathbb R$.
$3.$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n =\frac{1}{2}$ , then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exists in $\mathbb R$.
$4.$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n =0$ , then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.
For the first two options, I have having counter-example as $a_n=n$. So the first two options are not correct. For the third  option, it seems that $a_n$ is approx to $\frac{1}{2}\max\{a_1,\cdots a_n\}$. How to handle the last two options?

Consider $a_n=n$. Then 1 and 2 are false.
If $\lim b_n<1$, then there exists $N$ s.t. for $\forall n>N$, $a_n\neq \max\{a_1,\cdots,a_n\}$. Hence there exists $m\in\{1,2,\cdots,N\}$ s.t. $a_m\geq a_n$ for $\forall n$, which implies that $b_n=\frac{a_n}{a_m},\forall n>N$. Thus 3 and 4 are true.

please write more details if possible.  Thank you .

How you say that $b_n= \frac{a_n}{b_m}$?

$a_m$ is the largest among all $a_n$, so $b_n=\frac{a_n}{a_m}$.

@DJECN for that we have to show that sequence is bounded

Got the point . Thank you.
